# Do filters break colorizeExclusions in Flex 4.5 skins, and if so, is there a workaround?

Tags: apache-flex, filter, skinning, flex-spark, dropshadow

I have created an MXML spark button skin in Flex 4.5 that seems to work wonderfully, except that in the down-state, it ignores my **colorizeExclusions** array (which is currently protecting the text label and the highlight on the button).  The *only* difference between the up-state and the down-state is that I am applying an inner drop shadow in the down-state.

StackOverflow won't let me post images, because I'm a new user, so I've posted some elsewhere:

[Up State](http://malkyne.org/images/stackoverflow/button_up.png)

[image: up state]

[Down State](http://malkyne.org/images/stackoverflow/button_down.png)

[image: down state]

See how the highlight and text are colorized with the blue color, in the second picture?  That's just plain *wrong*.

If I place no state restrictions on this inner shadow, I see the same issue: My colorizeExclusions are ignored, so it does not appear to have anything to do with the states, or any state-specific CSS (which there isn't any of, in this case, anyway).

Here's the button skin code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
               xmlns:fxg="assets.fxg.*"
               minWidth="18" minHeight="18"
               alpha.disabled="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
    /** 
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    <![CDATA[         
        import spark.components.Group;
        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
        For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay", "highlight"];

        /** 
         * @private
         */     
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }  


    ]]>        
</fx:Script>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <!-- Background --> 
    <s:Group id="background" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <fxg:GlassButtonBack excludeFrom="over" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
        <fxg:GlassButtonBackBright includeIn="over" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
    </s:Group>


    <!-- layer 8: text -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay  -->

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" left="16" right="16" top="8" bottom="8"
             fontWeight="bold" horizontalCenter="0" maxDisplayedLines="1" textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle" verticalCenter="1"/>

    <s:Rect id="highlight" left="3" right="3" top="3" height="40%" radiusX="6" radiusY="6">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:entries>
                    <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" alpha="0.9" color="#FFFFFF" />
                    <s:GradientEntry ratio="1" alpha="0" color="#FFFFFF" />
                </s:entries>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:filters>
        <s:DropShadowFilter includeIn="down" inner="true" color="#000000" blurX="10" blurY="10" angle="90"/>

    </s:filters>

</s:Group>
```

Does anyone have any idea what on earth is going on here?  Is this a Flex bug?  Is there a workaround?  Did I do something stupid?  I'm really at a loss, here.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick overview :

```
static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay", "highlight"];
```

I don't think that should be static, try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: It's static in spark.skins.spark.ButtonSkin.  Also, I tried removing the static, just for the heck of it, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Problem is in your background area.  Remove / comment that section and the problem goes away as far as I can test.   Can you post the fxp?

Comment: Nate, when I commented out that area, it did not make the problem go away, I'm afraid.  So, it would seem that it has nothing to do with my fxgs.